# If a civilization could build wormholes, what else could they build?

Tags: physics, faster-than-light

I'll start out by apologizing that my knowledge of physics is limited.

But moving on.  As I understand it, in order to make a wormhole you'd need an absurd amount of negative mass to keep the wormhole stable and open.

Let's say that a civilization found some way to produce the amounts of negative mass necessary to make wormholes.  Do we know of any other potential applications for such exotic matter?  Or will they only be able to make wormholes with this stuff?

Comment: Asking us 21st century people about the applications of exotic matter and the energy amounts involved in making it... Is like asking the ancient greek about the applications of alternsting current and machines. We don't understand exotic matter very well, and we don't even know that it may exist at all. But if it does, and we master it, the limits to applications is imagination.

Comment: Time travel, for one. The applications of that is worth a whole other question.

Comment: I voted to close this as 'opinion-based,' since there is no good way to determine what the correct answer is. If you think you have a way, you should put your correct answer selection criteria in the question.

Comment: @kingledion Too broad, I can see.  But opinion-based?  Do not be idiotic!  I asked, very clearly, a question that was NOT opinion-based.  Whether or not there are KNOWN potential applications for exotic matter is hardly a matter of personal opinion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They could build basically anything they want anywhere.

With wormholes you can siphon off matter and energy from a star.

So You have an unlimited source of power (heat differential is power potential) and an unlimited source of matter.  Even if all you could get was hydrogen, you could use that power to transmute it into any element you want, with things as "simple" as giant particle accelerators.

They would have a unified force theory too.  So at that point pretty much anything you dream up they could do.

Ice planet, no problem wormhole some heat from close to the sun.  Desert planet, no problem wormhole some of the heat out to deep space. Dry land, no problem, wormhole some water in there.

Need a new space station, just wormhole it into orbit.

So a better question would be, if I had wormholes what can't I build.

Answer (score 2):

One application would be infinite propulsion that will not require propellant.

Positive masses are attracted by both other positive masses and negative masses.

Negative masses are repelled by both other negative masses and positive masses.

So arranging a positive and negative mass near each other will result in the positive mass moving toward the negative mass and the negative mass moving away from the negative mass.

Comment: "Negative masses repel both other negative masses and positive masses." where did you find that? Any source?

Comment: I actually should have written that as "Negative masses are repelled by both other negative masses and positive masses."  A negative mass results in a negative acceleration or, stated more clearly, acceleration in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

A wormhole is essentially a black hole formed into a ring.  If you can build that,  you could build anything large and massive.